# Group by contiguous dates and Count

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which contains information about reports being accessed along with the Date.I need to group reports being accessed according to a date range and count them.

I'm using T-SQL

Table

```
EventId   ReportId   Date
60          4         11/24/2015
59          11        11/23/2015
58          6         11/22/2015
57          11        11/22/2015
56          9         11/21/2015
55          3         11/20/2015
54          5         11/20/2015
53          6         11/19/2015
52          5         11/19/2015 
51          4         11/18/2015
50          3         11/17/2015
49          9         11/16/2015
```

If days' difference is 3 then I need result in the format

```
StartDate    EndDate     ReportsAccessed
11/22/2015   11/24/2015    4
11/19/2015   11/21/2015    5
11/16/2015   11/18/2015    3
```

but the difference between days could change.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: Can you assume that there will not be any gaps in the set of dates that appear in the DB?

Comment: What happens if there is a remain? For instance, if we group the data by 4 days, should the 1-day section be the closest result or the farthest?

Comment: Is there a table for date ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have values for all the dates, then you can calculate the difference in days between each date and the maximum (or minimum) date.  Then divide this by three and use that for aggregation:

```
select min(date), max(date), count(*) as ReportsAccessed
from (select t.*, max(date) over () as maxd
      from table t
     ) t
group by (datediff(day, date, maxd) / 3)
order by min(date);
```

"3" is what I think you are referring to as the "difference in days".

Comment: You should've mentioned what happens when you don't have values for all dates. Having date ranges that aren't always 3 days might not be an issue for him.

Comment: I have already marked julien's answer as correct but your answer is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Those 2 blocks are simply for added clarity on what parameters you'd have to change

```
DECLARE @t as TABLE(
id int identity(1,1),
reportId int,
dateAccess date)

DECLARE @NumberOfDays int=3;
```

And here comes the actual select

```
Select StartDate, EndDate, COUNT(reportId) from 
(
    select *, 
        DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(DAY, dateAccess, maxdate.maxdate)%@NumberOfDays, dateAccess) as EndDate,
        DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(DAY, dateAccess, maxdate.maxdate)%@NumberOfDays-@NumberOfDays+1, dateAccess) as StartDate
    from @t, (select MAX(dateAccess) maxdate from @t t2) maxdate
) results
GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate
ORDER BY StartDate desc
```

There are a few places I'm unsure if it's optimized or not, for instance cross joining with select max(date) instead of using a subquery, but that returns the exact result from your OP.

Basically, I simply split the entries into groups based on how far they are from the `MAX(date)`, and then use a `COUNT`. On that note, it might be more useful to use `COUNT(distinct ...)` otherwise if someone looks at the document #9 3 times, it will tell you tha 3 documents were checked, but only 1 was truly looked at.

The upside with using `MAX(date)` over `MIN(date)` is that your first group will always have the maximal amount of days. This will prove very useful if you want to compare the last few periods to the average. The downside is that you don't have stable data. With every new entry (assuming it's a new day), your query will cycle itself to produce a new set of results. If you wanted to graph the data, you'd be better comparing to MIN(date) that way the first days won't change when you add a new one.

Depending on the usage, it could even be useful to extrapolate the number of accesses done in the last period (in that case `MIN(date)` is also preferable).

---

Here's an adaptation of Gordon's answer that's probably *much* more optimized (it's at the very least much more aesthetic) :

```
SELECT DateADD(day, -datediff(day, dateAccess, maxdate)/3*3, maxdate) as EndDate, 
       DateADD(day, (-datediff(day, dateAccess, maxdate)/3+1)*3, maxdate) as StartDate, 
       count(reportId)
from (select *, MAX(dateAccess) over() as maxdate from @t) t
GROUP BY datediff(day, dateAccess, maxdate)/3, maxdate
```

Comment: You should definitely check out Gordon's answer. If you have entries for every days, his answer is far better. If you don't, I actually modified it to calculate the StartDate and EndDate.

Answer (score 0):

I will insist that most efficient way of doing this is to use tally table. That way you are getting sargable predicates with all benefits from indexes on date column:

```
declare @c int = 3

;with minmax as(select min(date) as mind, max(date) as maxd from t),
tally as(select @c * (-1 + row_number() over(order by(select null))) as rn 
         from master..spt_values),
intervals as(select dateadd(dd, rn, mind) as f, dateadd(dd, rn + @c - 1, mind) t
             from tally t cross join minmax m where dateadd(dd, rn, mind) <= maxd)
select i.f as [from], i.t as [to], count(*) as reeports
from intervals i
join t on t.date >= i.f and t.date <= i.t
group by i.f, i.t
```

Explanation: `minmax` selects minimum date and maximum date from table.
`tally` generates numbers from 0 to N(depends on system, but enougth to calc intervals). `intervals` selects resulting intervals. The last part is simple join on intervals to calculate counts per interval.

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c61d1/5